# Why is the inverse of $y=b^x$ $y=\log_b(x)$ instead of $x=\log_b(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, inverse-function

As I understand it, the relationship between $y=b^x$ would be written logarithmically as $\log_b(y)=x$, but I'm watching a video on khan academy where he states the inverse of $y=b^x$ is $\log_b(x)=y$. Is the logarithmic form of an exponential equation not the inverse of that equation?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you sure that they are stating exactly that the inverse of $y = b^x$ is $\log_b(x) = y$, and not simply that the graph of $\log_b(x) = y$ is the inverse of the graph of $y = b^x$?

Comment: It’s a matter of how you are writing / talking about it. Many mathematicians when they have an equation they are actually talking about the function on the right hand side of some free variable, which by convention is $x$. So, looking for the inverse, they are saying what is the function whose free parameter is the inversion. Therefore they use $x$ for the free parameter in both cases. 

What you did was “solve for x” which isn’t necessarily wrong, it’s just that it has the free parameter with a different label than usual.

Comment: [This answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/13068/745) might help clear things up.